# Determine Tomcat Root - Getting 404 for all root files

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

How do I determine the location of the tomcat root?  For some reason its not in the normal ~\webapps\ROOT location.  I have an app running under tomcat.  The app only partially loads because its needs a file in the ROOT, but apparently I don't know where the root is because I keep getting this:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [16/Dec/2015:14:57:11 -0500] "GET /en_US_Resource.swf HTTP/1.1" 404 999
```

I'm running Tomcat 7 via Eclipse.  I've copied that file to EVERY possible directory I can think of.

So my questions:

1) How can I determine the ROOT directory of a running tomcat instance?

2) What config files can change the ROOT directory location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this file: ~/conf/Catalina/localhost/.xml. this was redefining the root.  It had this entry.  I removed the file from this location & ROOT was fine.

```
<Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="C:\Workspace\project\project-web" workDir="C:\Workspace\project\work" />
```